# JWplayer - cant play hls link - m3u8

Tags: jquery, jwplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I use jwplayer 7 for stream hls link ( m3u8 - [example link](http://ir.edge.live.irib.ir:1935/simahamrah/smil:tv1/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC84LzIwMTYgMTo0MDo1MiBQTSZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPVVKOGFqaFhxZTZZSGhiMHVRcUcrR1E9PSZ2YWxpZG1pbnV0ZXM9MTA=) )

[example page](http://mobile-tv.ir/#/channel/?id=1&type=1)

hls link is correct , but jwplayer cant find source

Answer (score 1):

Your hls stream works in the JW Player stream tester, but when I force the type: hls for your stream, it get the error. I see you have included that parameter in your player setup, please take that out and let me know if that works. http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester/

Answer (score 0):

The link to the `.m3u8` file is returning a `403 Forbidden`. That will explain why JWPlayer can't access the file.

Comment: i set wrong link , fix it now , please check agaain